# How to force \author and logo on title page into a flexible position in memoir?

Tags: memoir, titles

I fixed a previous problem, by creating a `tabular`, but unfortunately it doesn't work with my current problem. This is what my current setup produces:

[image]

And this is what I was aiming for:

[image]

As you can se with the top two red boxes, is what I made with `tabular`, but it won't work with the authors and the logo.

My preamble is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,article,twocolumn]{memoir}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \maketitlehooka
    \vskip -1cm%
  {\@bspredate %
  \hspace{-0.9em}
    \begin{tabular}{p{2cm} p{5cm}}
    Submitted: & \suB\\
    Published: & \puB 
    \end{tabular}
    \@bspostdate}
  \maketitlehookb
  {\@bspretitle \@title \@bsposttitle}
  \maketitlehookc
  {\@bspreauthor \@author \@bspostauthor}
  \maketitlehookd
  \par
  \vskip 0.5em
}
\makeatother
%-------------------------------------------------------------
\pretitle{\begin{flushleft}\huge\bfseries\vskip 0cm}
\title{Very VERY long title, which stretches over two lines... more text}
\posttitle{\par\vskip1em{\normalfont\normalsize\scshape \subtitle \par\vfill}\end{flushleft}}
\newcommand{\subtitle}{Name of institution\\
\hfill\includegraphics[height=2cm]{frog.jpg}
\vspace{-0cm}}
\author{JONES aaaa\thanks{\texttt{Email}} \and 
JONES bbbb\thanks{\texttt{Email}} \and 
JONES cccc\thanks{\texttt{Email}} \and 
John AAA \and 
John BBB \and 
John CCC
}
```

Hopefully some of you LaTeX pros can help me out here.

Comment: You should not use hooks and stuff like that if you use this just once (imho). Simply [customize your titlepage](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation#Create_the_title_for_a_report_or_book). If you need it multiple times, [make it a bit more robust](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation#A_title_to_be_re-used_multiple_times).

Comment: Good idea. Unfortunately I still don't know how to produce the desired layout for the `titlepage`.

Comment: Just use two `minipage`s or `tabular`s as you did before. But you have to scrap all that predefined stuff and start from scratch (that's why the link above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by creating two minipages, one with the authors and one with the logo.

So it looks like this: 
[image]

Still the name of institution is below the field for author names, but it's the best I could do at the moment:

[image]

And my fix is written out here:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
  \newpage
  \null
%  \vskip 2em%
%  \vspace*{\droptitle}
  \maketitlehooka %before \title
    \vskip -1cm%
  {\@bspredate %
  \hspace{-0.9em}
    \begin{tabular}{p{2cm} p{5cm}}
    Submitted: & \suB\\
    Published: & \puB 
    \end{tabular}
    \@bspostdate}
  \maketitlehookb % before \author
  {\@bspretitle \@title \@bsposttitle}
  \maketitlehookc % before \date  
  {\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}%
  \@bspreauthor %
  \@author %
  \@bspostauthor%
   \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}%
    \centering
    \vskip2em\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{frog.jpg}%
    \vskip0em\scshape\institution
    \end{minipage}
    }
  \maketitlehookd % after \date
  \vskip 1em
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Do you know what `maketitlehookc` and similar are doing, what purpose they serve? How the generation of the title works?

Comment: Not quite. My understanding is limited, but from what I've picked up, the different hooks are setup for different positions in `make title`, like `%before \title` and so on. I read the links you gave in a previous comment, but since I'm not that good with LaTeX, it seemed overwhelming for me to build the `titlepage` from scratch, which is why doing this small workaround with the different hooks felt fine for me.

Comment: Building it from scratch is much easier.